# Using LocalDate in Serialized JSF Managed Bean

Tags: jsf, java-8, sonarqube, java-ee-7, sonarlint

I'm currently working on an Java EE application with Java 8. And, I have a SessionScoped managed bean as below. Since LocalDate is value based, SONAR check throws me an error saying, "Value based should not be serialized"

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private LocalDate startDate;
    /*getters and setters */
}
```

How to handle this situation. Is it fine to make the variable **transient**? Is there any impact, if I make it transient? Or I can ignore this SONAR error?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I can remove this rule from Sonar. But, I would like to understand, what we are supposed to do, if our requirement is to have value based objects in Serializable class.

Comment: Apologies, added the tags now.